# How to edit object in array using Firebase + Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

In my Firebase + Angular (with AngularFire) app I have an array of objects which are formatted as a table with ng-repeat. Each row is a different object.

I want to add option to "assign" particular object to a user who is currently logged in with Firebase Simple Login. I added function assignTo(item) similar to deleteItem(item) but that doesn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div ng-controller="itemsCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- table row aka object starts here -->
    <td>
      {{ item.assignedTo}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <form ng-submit="assignTo(item)">
       <button ng-click="items.$save(item)"class="btn btn-default">Assign</button>
      </form>               
        </td>
        <td>
          <form ng-submit="deleteItem(item)">
        <button ng-click="items.$remove(item)">Remove</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<!-- table row aka object ends here -->
...
</div>
```

and here's my controller

```
app.controller("itemsCtrl", ["$scope", '$rootScope', "$firebase", "simpleLogin",
   function($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, simpleLogin) {
     var ref = new Firebase("https://--------.firebaseio.com/");
     $scope.items = [];
     var sync = $firebase(ref);
     $scope.items = sync.$asArray();
     $rootScope.auth = simpleLogin;

    ...

     $scope.assignTo = function(assignedTo) {
       $scope.items[i].assignedTo = $rootScope.auth.user.displayName;
       $scope.items[i].$save(i)
     };
   }
 ]);
```

## UPDATE: this solved the problem

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">
...
<td>
<button ng-click="assignTo(key)" class="btn btn-default">Assign</button>
</td>
```

and

```
 $scope.assignTo = function(key) {
   console.log($scope.items[key].assignedTo);
   $scope.items[key].assignedTo = $rootScope.auth.user.displayName;;
   $scope.items.$save(key);
 };
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a regular forum. While it's great that you managed to solve it in your own, we handle that differently here. Please provide your solution as an answer below. Then accept your own answer to make it clear to everyone.

Comment: As to the actual solution: cool, I didn't know about the `(key, item)` trick. I normally get the key of the item using `item.$id`.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I'll handle my further questions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with arrays here, using `(key, item)` isn't ideal (this is a construct for iterating objects).

Angular provides the special `$index` variable which represents `i` in your example above:

```
<button ng-click="assignTo($index)">Assign</button>
```

Also, you already have the item when you make the call, so there is no need to look it up by key or index ($save will also accept the actual item in place of the index ):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>
    <button ng-click="assignTo(item)">Assign</button>
  </td>

$scope.assignTo = function(item) {
   item.assignedTo = $rootScope.auth.user.displayName;;
   $scope.items.$save(item);
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for advice Kato but when i refactored code by your advice i've got an error 
    TypeError: object is not a function at k.$scope.assignTo